# The running results in matlab and R language are inconsistent

Tags: r, matlab

> matlab

```
Yr=Y;
Us{1}=Yr*C;
U=Us{1};
Fxy=Y-Us{1}*C
```

> R language

```
Yr <- Y
Us <- list()
Us[[1]] <- Yr %*% C
U <- Us[[1]] 
Fxy <- Y-(U[[1]] %*% t(C))
```

The U, C, and Y values in the two pieces of code are the same except for the number of digits left after the decimal point. In matlab, four digits are kept, and in R, the calculation is accurate. Y is a 246 2 matrix, C is a 2 1 vector, and U is a 246-row list with dimensions that can be multiplied. Why does it work in matlab and R? Different results

Comment: [How can I change the way MATLAB displays the significant digits of floating point numbers?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99743-how-can-i-change-the-way-matlab-displays-the-significant-digits-of-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: The linked question seems different at first sight, but it’s the exact same problem you’re experiencing, and the answer there is your solution.